# function of generic container of specific specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, vector, generic-programming

I'm trying to write an algorithm that should work with different containers (std::vector, QVector) containing the same type:

```
template<class Container>
boolean findpeaks(cv::Mat &m, Container<std::pair<int, double>> &peaks) {
    // do stuff
    peaks.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 1.0));

    return true;
}
```

This one gives me

> 'Container' is not a template

```
template<template<typename> class Container>
```

I get:

> error: no matching function for call to 'findpeaks(cv::MatExpr, std::vector >&)'
>
> ...
>
> note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
> error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)

Calling code:

```
cv::Mat m(data, true);
std::vector<std::pair<int, double>> peaks;

QVERIFY(daf::findpeaks(m.t(), peaks));
```

I've also tried something like this:

```
template<template< template<typename, typename> typename > class Container>
```

> warning: ISO C++ forbids typename key in template template parameter; use -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z [-Wpedantic]

And some more errors...

Comment: "the same type" shown is not a type. It's a function. `template<template<typename> class Container>` is not a valid template declaration. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, the template declaration is invalid, the question is to find a valid one :) "the same type" doesn't refer to the function, the "algorithm that should work with" refers to the function. "same type" refers to std::pair<int, double>. Meaning any container of those pairs, that supports push_back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as expressed with @Barry's answer, I don't think you need a template template parameter here.

However, you seem to have concern about expressing "a container that supports `push_back` with a pair of..."

I suggest you to express this constraint in a sfinae constraint expression instead. Even if your parameter is explicitly requiring `std::pair` to be in the first template parameter of a class, it doesn't mean it has a `push_back` function, and doesn't mean the supposedly existing `push_back` is taking a `std::pair` as parameter.

Arguments of a function is currently a bad way of expressing what a template type should be able to do, or should be. You'll have to wait for concepts for that.

In the meantime, you can use a sfinae constraint in your function signature that explicitly express that you need a type that has a member `push_back` function that accept a `std::pair`:

```
template<class Container>
auto findpeaks(cv::Mat &m, Container& peaks)
        // Using trailing return type
        -> first_t<bool, decltype(peaks.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 1.0)))>
        // Here's the constraint -^    that expression need to be valid
    {

    // do stuff
    peaks.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 1.0));

    return true;
}
```

`first_t` can be implemented that way:

```
template<typename T, typename...>
using first_t = T;
```

For the function to exist, the expression inside the `decltype` must be valid. If the contraint is not satified, the compiler will try other overloads of the function `findpeaks`.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket ')'  after make_pair. Other than that, take my upvote for your arcane template magic you C++ wizard.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer thanks for pointing out the error. Should be fixed by now.

Comment: *Concept* might help in the future.

Answer (score 5):

[std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has two template parameters.

> ```
> template<  
>     class T,
>     class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> > class vector;
> ```

And `QVector` has one. You can do it with [variadic template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack):

```
template<template <typename...> class Container>
bool findpeaks(cv::Mat &m, Container<std::pair<int, double>> &peaks) {
    // do stuff
    peaks.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 1.0));

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you actually need `Container` to be a class template? Just make it a normal type:

```
template<class Container>
boolean findpeaks(cv::Mat &m, Container& peaks) {
    // do stuff
    peaks.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 1.0));

    return true;
}
```

This will let you use other containers that are potentially not templates. Like, `struct MySpecialPairContainer { ... };`

Comment: While that is a simpler solution, I'd like to have std::pair<..> in the signature, to make clear that this is what you're getting :)

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer You can express this in a sfinae constraint instead of the function parameters.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot mhh, I'm not sure how I would go about doing that :)

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer I've written an answer that explain how to do this. Don't forget to upvote this one (Barry's one) too, as it raises pretty good points.

Answer (score 2):

You may do

```
template<template <typename ...> class Container>
bool findpeaks(cv::Mat &m, Container<std::pair<int, double>> &peaks) {
    // do stuff
    peaks.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 1.0));

    return true;
}
```

Your problem is that `std::vector` has 2 template parameters, the type `T` and an allocator.

But you can do even simpler:

```
template<typename Container>
bool findpeaks(cv::Mat& m, Container& peaks) {
    // do stuff
    peaks.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 1.0));

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you shouldn't over specify.  If I wrote:

```
struct my_thing {
  void push_back( std::pair<int, double> const& ) {}
};
```

shouldn't I be able to pass `my_thing` to your `findpeaks`?

There is absolutely no need for the `template<class...>class Container` template within the function, so requring it in the interface is an overspecification.

What you need is a sink (graph theoretical sink -- a sink is where things flow into, and don't flow out of) that consumes pairs of `int, double`.  Ideally you want to be able to pass in a container without extra boilerplate.

```
template<class T>
struct sink:std::function<void(T)> {
  using std::function<T>::function;
  // more
};
```

now your function looks like:

```
bool findpeaks(cv::Mat &m, sink<std::pair<int, double>const&> peaks) {
  // do stuff
  peaks(std::make_pair(1, 1.0));

  return true;
}
```

and as a bonus, you can now put it into a cpp file instead of a header.  (The dispatching costs for a `std::function` are modest).

This does require that you wrap the second parameter up at the call site:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, double>> v;
if(findpeaks( matrix, [&](auto&& e){v.push_back(decltype(e)(e));} ) {
  // ...
```

which you might not like.  Because we didn't use a naked `std::function` but instead a `sink`, we can get around this.  First we write a metatrait, then some traits.

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class alwaysvoid, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply=details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;
```

This is a meta trait that lets us write other traits.

```
template<class C, class X>
using push_back_result = decltype( std::declval<C>().push_back( std::declval<X>() ) );

template<class C, class X>
using can_push_back = can_apply< push_back_result, C, X >;
```

now we have a trait `can_push_back` that is `true_type` if and only if you can push an `X` into the container `C`.

We now augment sink:

```
template<class T, class Base=std::function<void(T)>>
struct sink:Base {
  using Base::Base;
  template<class C,
    std::enable_if_t< can_push_back< C&, T >{}, int> =0
  >
  sink( C& c ):
    Base( [&](auto&& t){ c.push_back(decltype(t)(t)); } )
  {}
  sink()=default;
  sink(sink const&)=default;
  sink(sink &&)=default;
  sink& operator=(sink const&)=default;
  sink& operator=(sink &&)=default;
};
```

This newly augmented `sink` now can be passed a container that supports `.push_back(T)` and automatically writes a function that solves the problem for you.

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, double>> v;
if(findpeaks( matrix, v ) {
  // ...
```

That just works.

We can do the same for containers that support `.insert(T)`, and after that we can use `std::set<T>` or even `std::map<int, double>` as a sink for your algorithm:

```
std::set<std::pair<int, double>> s;
if(findpeaks( matrix, s ) {
  // ...
std::map<int, double> m;
if(findpeaks( matrix, m ) {
  // ...
```

Finally, this also supports mocking.  You can write a test-sink that helps unit-test your `findpeaks` algorithm directly.

I find the concept of `sink` used sufficiently often that having a `sink` type that supports these kind of things makes my code clearer, and reduces its dependency on any one kind of container.

Performance wise, the cost of the type erasure in `std:function` is modest.  if you really need performance improvement, swapping `sink<X>` for `sink<X, F>` where `F` is a free parameter is possible, and writing `make_sink` that creates a `sink` where `Base` is a lambda, should work with near zero changes in the body of the code.  But before you do that, you can work on higher level optimizations, like having the output into `sink` be processed in a streaming manner, or fed to an async queue, or the like.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, this is some cool stuff. If I was writing this as part of a general purpose library for the general public that might make sense. But here, this is waaaay over-engineered. The code base simply mixes std::vector and QVector and I didn't want to commit to one. Even if I did, it wouldn't be horrible. But by adding the variadic template bit, I add one line and the caller doesn't have to care.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer Take a `std::function<void(std::pair<int, double> const&)>` as your sink.  Getting the code out of the header is usually worth it, and the glue is tiny.